# Delphi7: PageControl MouseMove while drag and dropping on it

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have the following problem.

There's a pagecontrol on my form and I want to **activate** a certain tabsheet and then **drag and drop** (from explorer) to a scrollbox on the tabsheet. (each tabsheet has a scrollbox)
I have code to activate a tab when you mousemove over the pagecontrol. (see code below) The problem is that when I **drag a file from explorer** the mousemove never fires when I hover/mousemove over the pagecontrol while still dragging.
Also tried to set `DragAcceptFiles(pagecontrol.Handle,true);` but that also doesn't help.

```
procedure TForm2.PageControlMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
var 
  tabindex : Integer;
begin
  tabindex := PageControl.IndexOfTabAt( X, Y );
  PageControl.ActivePageIndex := tabindex;
end;
```

Any ideas/solutions guys and girls?

Thanks.

SoulBlade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `DragAcceptFiles()` you don't get the necessary information, only when data is finally dropped onto the drop target will a `WM_DROPFILES` message be sent to the window handle registered with `DragAcceptFiles()`.

If you use OLE drag and drop you will get much more control. The [Drag and Drop Component Suite for Delphi](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop) by Anders Melander implements everything in an easy to install set of components. Use any of the drop target objects, set its `Target` property to the pagecontrol on which you want to drop, and use its `OnDragOver` event to activate the correct tabsheet.

Comment: I'll accept it as an answer. Any other ways without 3rd party components?

Comment: @SoulBlade: Sure, you could implement the `IDropTarget` interface yourself (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679679%28VS.85%29.aspx), but why go to all that trouble?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Too much shlep to do myself. Anyway I installed the suite and it's working like a bomb. Thanks.